# From retrofit onResponse, retrieve a field answer and use it again

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm prety sure there is already an answer to my question but I don't really understand their answer (and not feeling confident to change too much my code x'))

So as the title says I'm using retrofit, I can call the API, I have the answer.
But after that, I want to retrieve one field from the answer, to use it later (like a token needed to do more API call)

**Here is the code in question** :

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.orange.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ApiService service = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

        String userName = "lCjTF83Ul61a0UXe0NSWcW459pnUDXQE";
        String passWord = "AGCEGvixfiAA513P";
        String base = userName + ":" + passWord;

        String grant_type = "client_credentials";
        String authHeader = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(base.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
        Call<Authentification> authentificationCall = service.getTokenAccess(authHeader, grant_type);

        authentificationCall.enqueue(new Callback<Authentification>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Authentification> call, Response<Authentification> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                Authentification authentification = response.body();
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + statusCode);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Authentification> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());

            }


        });
    }
```

**And the code of the answer**:

```
public class Authentification {

    @SerializedName("token_type")
    @Expose
    private String tokenType;
    @SerializedName("access_token")
    @Expose
    private String accessToken;
    @SerializedName("expires_in")
    @Expose
    private String expiresIn;

    public String getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public String getExpiresIn() {
        return expiresIn;
    }

    public void setExpiresIn(String expiresIn) {
        this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
    }
```

}

So in the answer there is a field "access_token" i would like.

**I wanted to do something like that : (after the Log.d in onResponse)**

```
final String abc = response.body().getAccessToken();
```

But then I want to use it in the other class, in the other retrofit instance

```
private void AppelReseauNRJ(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.orange.com/orangeradio/v1/radios/nrj/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ApiRadioList service1 = retrofit.create(ApiRadioList.class);



    String Zetoken = "Bearer " + ;

    Call<GetStream> listRadioCall = service1.getRadio(Zetoken);
    listRadioCall.enqueue(new Callback<GetStream>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GetStream> call, Response<GetStream> response) {
            int statusCode = response.code();
            GetStream getStream = response.body();
            Log.d (TAG, "onResponse: " + statusCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GetStream> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

(Exactly where Zetoken is)

Can you give me some line of thought, some idea?

Thx (I'll look at your answer after lunch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your token in SharedPreference for later usage.

In your login api result , Save your access token

```
SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("myPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor= preferences.edit();
editor.putString("token", response.body().getAccessToken());
editor.apply();
```

Retrieve this token when ever you need (in another activity).

```
SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String token = preferences.getString("token","");
```

Comment: i try your solution and looks great, when i look on debug mode, i have the good header.
I need to solve an error that appear (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $" i'll look into it, and come back to you if it work 
Thx :)

Comment: So i fixed my issue and your method work P E R F E C T L Y :D - THX